# Regarding file name consists of current GMT time

Tags: java

I have to name one file as per the current london time stamp so I prefer to go for this way as shown below ..

/

```
/the time zone for London.
        TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm", Locale.UK);
        formatter.setTimeZone(london);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        String t =fileIdentifier+"-"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+"."+"doc";
```

But now instead of Current london time I was trying  current GMT time to be 
dispalayed in file name , please advise what modifications need to be done in order to dispaly the current GMT time . I have come up with this solution..

```
TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm");
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        String t =fileIdentifier+"-"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+"."+"doc";
```

Please advise does my above approach will display the current GMT time in file name or not

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please advise does my approach will display current GMT time or not in the file name itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `TimeZone` to your `SimpleTimeFormat` object by using [`DateFormat#setTimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) before formatting the `Date`. Here's an example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
formatter.setTimeZone(gmt);
System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
```

Here in Peru (GMT -5) is 12:17 a.m. Current output is:

```
07-15-2013 00:17 //no GMT
07-15-2013 05:17 //GMT
```